# Can't open software center Help!

Tags: software-center

I am totally new to Linux so I don't know how to do anything :S I was trying to open Software Center ( to install spotify) but I always get this error message:

```
Please run this software with administrative rights. To do so, run this program with kdesudo.
```

Hope that somebody can help me with this

Comment: How do you open Software Center?

Comment: you can't install Spotify via the software center. Go to spotify.com and they have a guide to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the package "Software-center"

open a terminal window, and type

```
kdesudo software-center
```

if that doesnt work try

```
sudo software-center
```